# Is there an API for Apple App Analytics?

Tags: ios, iphone, analytics, ios11, itunes

I'm trying to extract the analytics information of my App in the Apple App Store using an API.

I have been able to just download the information but I need a more automate solution.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-analytics/
https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/App%20Analytics_Overview

And I cannot find any information in the documentation. Any Idea ?

Comment: you need not to add any  Apple App Store API for analytics, Apple does this on behalf of you or you can say it's inbuilt analytics in app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants a way to _extract_ data from iTunes Analytics, not provide it.

Comment: Maybe you can use this command line tool: https://help.apple.com/itc/appsreporterguide/

Comment: Just in case, there is an API now: https://developer.apple.com/app-store-connect/api/

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74714722/11724419

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple hasn't officially made a real API available for any of the data iTunes Connect displays, but we at Appfigures have.

We connect to Apple and do all the heavy lifting, and make sales, ads, usage, ranks, featured, ratings, and reviews data available through a simple REST interface.

Check out the documentation at https://docs.appfigures.com

*FYI - The API provides access for Android and Windows apps as well.*

Comment: Is this needed now that there is an API? Thanks.