# Is there an Apple Store Connect API for fetching an app's impressions, product pageviews, downloads?

Tags: app-store-connect

When I was going through the Apple Store Connect API docs, there are APIs to download Sales and Trends reports.

Sales and Trends API: (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_sales_and_trends_reports)

But I specifically want the following metrics:

- App Impressions
- Product Page Views
- App Units/Downloads
- Source type
- Territories

Is there any API available in Apple Store Connect for these values?

Comment: Did you find something?

Comment: Nothing as of now

Answer (score 0):

Hi I found it by checking the network tab from chrome developer tools, apparently, your browser sends a POST request to
`https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/analytics/api/v1/data/time-series`